# I want to write a javascript code to fetch data from koha (An ILS)

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, xml

I'm a beginner in learning Javascipt. What I want to do is to fetch data from Koha library system using javascript code. Koha uses Apache2 web server and MySQL database to store catalogues.

My code was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"><h2>Result</h2></div>


<script>
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/koha/svc/bib/3?userid=user&password=user1", false);
  xhttp.send();

  xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
  txt = "";
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
   }
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It doesnt work.

When I type the url:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/koha/svc/bib/3?userid=user&password=user1

in my browser I get this

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

    <record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd">
    <leader>00099nam a22000617a 4500</leader>
    <datafield tag="020" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">234234</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="245" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">Harry Potter</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="999" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="c">3</subfield>
    <subfield code="d">3</subfield>
    </datafield>
    </record>
```

I want to get the output using javascript. Please help!

Comment: Is jQuery something you can possible use?  It is MUCH easier to do AJAX requests with jQuery than natively.

Comment: Thanks for taking effort in typing the whole code. I will stick to jQuery if that's a better option. The code worked when I saved the displayed data as a xml file locally. What I want is to fetch the data from the koha server from the url : '127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/koha/svc/bib/… ' using Koha's svc http API. This link gives its documentation: wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_/svc/_HTTP_API.

Comment: which URL is used for fetch staff or OPAC?

Answer (score 0):

If `jQuery` is an option, I recommend using it for both your ajax call and your handling of XML.  I saved your xml results as file locally as "Temp.xml" and created the page below on a local web server.  The `$.get("Temp.xml")` call is an ajax call that pulls file into memory as an XML Document.  From there, I user jQuery to find the nodes I want and write them to the page.  (`document.write` is probably not the best way to get the data on the page, but it gets the job done for demonstration purposes.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"><h2>Result</h2></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    // Get the xml via a "GET" request.  When it's done, process the results.
    $.get("Temp.xml").done(function(xmlDoc) {
        // The resulting xml is basically a bunch of datafield nodes that contain
        // subfield nodes. Write each datafield values and then each of their
        // subfield values.
        $(xmlDoc).find("datafield").each(function(index, datafield) {
            // getAttribute can be used on native elements to get their attribute values...
            document.write('datafield[tag] = ' + datafield.getAttribute('tag'));
            document.write('<br>');

            // $(...) wraps an element with jQuery functionality and allows you quickly
            // and easily find / process particular notes.
            $(datafield).find("subfield").each(function(index, subfield) {
                document.write(' &nbsp; &nbsp; '); // for indentation
                document.write('subfield[code] = ' + subfield.getAttribute('code'));
                document.write(', '); // for indentation
                document.write('subfield = ' + subfield.textContent);
                document.write('<br>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking effort in typing the whole code. I will stick to jQuery  if that's a better option. The code worked when I saved the displayed data as a xml file locally. What I want is to fetch the data from the koha server from the url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/koha/svc/bib/3?userid=user&password=user1 ' using Koha's svc http API. This link gives its documentation: https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_/svc/_HTTP_API.

Comment: So, the parameter to $.get is the URL of your web service.  So all you need to do is change $.get("Temp.xml") to $.get("127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/koha/svc/bib") or whatever your web service is.  I don't have koha running locally, so my code example didn't include that, but it should work for you.

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work then. But later I found out that my browser didnt allow cross origin resource sharing. I added a chrome CORS extension and it worked! Thank you so much for the code and the explanation. I'm into jQuery now. :)